# Random Request Timeout with Lan switch

Tags: router, routing, ping, switch

#### Configuration

My router: FRITZ!Box 6490 ([manual](https://en.avm.de/fileadmin/user_upload/EN/Manuals/FRITZ_Box/Manual_FRITZBox_6490.pdf))
Switch: Netgear GS205 ([spec](https://www.cnet.com/products/netgear-gs205-switch-5-ports-unmanaged/specs/))

> Internet:
> Download 212 Mbit/s
> Upload 12.7 Mbit/s
> FRITZ!Box uses a DS Lite tunnel, IPv4 over DS Lite (Power Mode enabled 1 Gbit/s)
> Ehternet Driver Internet/Dublex configured to: **Auto Negation**

#### Problem

Without switch I have no packet loss, but when I connect my PC (tried windows 10 desktop and Linux ubuntu Laptop) I'm getting random packets loss between  2% and 10%.

```
Ping statistics for 8.8.8.8:
Packets: Sent = 186, Received = 182, Lost = 4 (2% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
Minimum = 14ms, Maximum = 89ms, Average = 19ms
```

When Im talking in skype/slack for example, packet loss increases

```
Ping statistics for 8.8.8.8:
Packets: Sent = 498, Received = 462, Lost = 36 (7% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
Minimum = 13ms, Maximum = 134ms, Average = 18ms
```

Even when I pinging router

```
Ping statistics for 192.168.178.1:
Packets: Sent = 345, Received = 320, Lost = 25 (7% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 6ms, Average = 0ms
```

arp-a

```
Interface: 192.168.178.28 --- 0x3
Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
192.168.178.1         c8-0e-14-ac-9d-fb     dynamic
192.168.178.20        e0-b9-a5-ce-0f-b2     dynamic
192.168.178.27        5c-e0-c5-f3-e7-29     dynamic
192.168.178.53        a0-48-1c-5c-77-dc     dynamic
192.168.178.254       c8-0e-14-ac-9d-fc     dynamic
192.168.178.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     static
224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static
239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static
255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
```

I tried:

- to change ethernet cabel
- realese/renew ip
- flush dns cache
- restart router

**Update 1:**
I replaced switch with other router and tried to use second router as switch. Packet loss gone. Can this switch be broken? Is there any way to test switch functionality?

What can cause packet loss in switch? Im really without any ideas..

**Update 2:**
Interesting test:

After connecting:
Main router (1Gbit/s) to other switch (100mbit/s) and to actual testing router (Netgear GS205 1Gbit/s) there is no request time outs.

Comment: run tests with and w/out the switch -- http://www.dslreports.com/speedtest or others -- look for [bufferbloat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bufferbloat) or other problems.  are all devices on the switch operating at 1Gbps? or are there devices on the switch that are running at 100Mbps?

Comment: Switch is 1Gbps, device is 1Gbps too. It has something with UDP connection,because skype always stucking.Event I ping successfuly other NIC, skype connection always time outs

Comment: I suspect a hardware problem in the switch. Get rid of switch, use another switch.

Comment: Note about your _update2_: if you can, try to test the original configuration (FRITZ!Box 6490 + Switch: Netgear GS205) at 100 and not at 1000. If the packet loss will drop you narrow your research field. Try to connect via wireless a computer at the maximum speed allowed (by _Fritz_...) and check if you have _timeout_ issues. Try to download  a huge file (maybe an iso) and check for the errors (and transfer speed). If the problem remains only when the 2 devices are connected at 1000 and disappears when a computer is directly (or via wireless) connected to _Fritz_ you know where the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

From your test it seems it's the switch problem, or at least a compatibility issue.

You can connect the switch to at least 2 NICs, they can be on the same computer or different ones, assign them IP address manually so they can ping each other, then do your test. Try different settings on NICs to solve compatibility issue, such as Jumbo frame, offload, etc.